# Table cell auto-set valign

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table

I have multiple tables where some of the table cells have large rowspans and I just realised that all of their valign values aren't set at all. Is there an easy way to set the valign to all table cells with a rowspan attribute to middle?

Either using CSS, html, Javascript or PHP. I am using them all right now, I just don't want to go through all 80 odd tables as each one took over an hour to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> set the valign to all table cells with a rowspan attribute to middle

in order to achieve that, you could use [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) as follows:

```css
td[rowspan] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

*Chris Coyier* has a [nice article](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) about this; You might want to consider that.

Comment: Yeh this is the best this to do... As I posted this I remembered that you could do this. Thanks anyway! I'll mark this as an answer as soon as it lets me.